# Conda: Virtual Environment Cannot be created

Tags: linux, anaconda, conda, centos7, anaconda3

I have installed conda (version: 23.7.4) in OS (centos 7.9.2009) but could not activate the environment.

```
username@blaze% conda activate base
usage: conda [-h] [--no-plugins] [-V] COMMAND ...
conda: error: argument COMMAND: invalid choice: 'activate' (choose from 'clean', 'compare', 'config', 'create', 'info', 'init', 'install', 'list', 'notices', 'package', 'remove', 'uninstall', 'rename', 'run', 'search', 'update', 'upgrade', 'build', 'content-trust', 'convert', 'debug', 'develop', 'doctor', 'index', 'inspect', 'metapackage', 'render', 'skeleton', 'token', 'env', 'pack', 'repo', 'verify', 'server')
```

The path has already added and I have double checked:

```
username@blaze% conda -V       
conda 23.7.4
```

What is the problem of that? How to fix it?

Comment: You need to first run `conda init`, and then restart the shell (or source the shell resource file, e.g., `source ~/.bashrc`).